# JQuery Simplemodal and Tabs Help Needed

Tags: asp.net, jquery, tabs, simplemodal

I've got an asp.net page containing a Textbox with an Autocomplete extender on it.
It's setup so the user can type a short reference code into the textbox and then choose from the list of matching codes returned by the autocomplete.

On the "select", I then call the server using JQuery.  I'm currently using $.get here....
The callback function from $.get checks for "success" and then displays a simple-modal dialog containing info about the item they've just selected.

```
if (sStatus == "success") {
        $.modal(sText, {
        overlayClose: true,
            appendTo:'form',
            onShow: function(dialog) {
                $("#ccTargets_tabContainer").tabs();
            },
            onClose: function(dialog) {
                $("#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>").val("");
                $.modal.close();
            }
        });
        $.ready();
    }
```

One of the bits of info being loaded here is a JQuery TABS setup, so the onShow function of the simplemodal is used to initiate the tabs which are within the simplemodal.

Now to the crux of my problem.
If I do multiple consecutive "autocompletes" on the same page it all works fine ***Unless I have selected a different tab on the tabs in the simplemodal*** ....If I select a different tab, close the simplemodal and then do another autocomplete I get a JQuery error which seems to relate to a selector doing something with the "old" selected tab that was on the "closed" modal.

I'm clearly missing some sort of cleardown / initialisation somewhere, but can't find what it is.  Help?

I've tried "tabs.destroy" before the modal call in the code above and I've tried a $.ready() call as indicated too....

UPDATE: Is it something to do with JQuery Tabs appending my addressbar URL with the selected tab's ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem.
It's with the "history" script that the tabs plugin normally uses.  Obviously as I am continually creating and destroying popups there is no history to speak of - it's all done outside of the normal app navigation.

I've removed the jquery.history_remote script and now it works just great!

Dave